# JQuery hover on image inside divisions is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The images should change whenever it is hovered but it is not working.

HTML

```
<div style="position:relative" id="banner-container">
<img src="banner-3308.png" data-pin-nopin="true">
<div id="sqm" style="position:absolute; top: 35px; left: 7px">
    <img id="sqm" src="b-3308-2a.png" alt=""/></a>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top: 52px; left: 7px">
    <img id="pmlc" src="b-3308-3.png" alt=""/>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top: 70px; left: 7px">
    <img id="wireless" src="b-3308-4.png" alt=""/>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top: 92px; left: 7px">
    <img id="dst" src="b-3308-5.png" alt=""/>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top: 26px; left: 387px">
    <img id="nb" src="b-3308-2b.png" alt=""/>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(fucntion()
{
     $("#banner-container").mouseover(function() {
        $("#sqm").hover(function(e) {
            $(this).attr("src","b-3308-2a-active.png");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).attr("src","b-3308-2a.png");    
        });
        $("#pmlc").hover(function(e) {
            $(this).attr("src","b-3308-3-active.png");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).attr("src","b-3308-3.png"); 
        });
        $("#wireless").hover(function(e) {
            $(this).attr("src","b-3308-4-active.png");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).attr("src","b-3308-4.png"); 
        });
        $("#dst").hover(function(e) {
            $(this).attr("src","b-3308-5-active.png");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).attr("src","b-3308-5.png"); 
        });
        $("#nb").hover(function(e) {
            $(this).attr("src","b-3308-2b-active.png");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).attr("src","b-3308-2b.png");    
        });
    });
});
```

I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Why are using event inside event? `hover` inside `mouseover`  ???

Comment: Only this can be done by `class` why are you using `id`?

Comment: This does not work only for the first image: <img src="/es-es/brands/rosemount/Level/Guided-Wave-Radar/3308a/PublishingImages/banner-3308.png"> Another possibility is: the path of your images is wrong. See console error messages for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in you code. Else your code is working.

not `$(document).ready(fucntion()` use `$(document).ready(function()`. function spell is wrong here.

Your first image is not working because you didn't give hover effect on it.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0ye4f8p/)**

Comment: Well that was one thank you. The other guy also said that i can't use it because of using hover inside mouseover.. well anyway thank you very much for the help!